# Unexpected output using lxml `.xpath()` and `for`

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have the following text

```
testing = """
<div>
<a>11</a>
</div>
<div>
<a>21</a>
<a>23</a>
</div>
"""
```

And I want to extract the text inside `<a></a>`. Below is my try,

```
testing = html.fromstring(testing)
testing = testing.xpath("//div")
[x.xpath("//a/text()") for x in testing]
```

The output is

```
[['11', '21', '23'], ['11', '21', '23'], ['11', '21', '23']]
```

But what I expect and want is

```
[['11'], ['21', '23']]
```

How can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testing.xpath("//div")` returns you a list of matching `div` nodes. For every `div` node, you ask to find all `a` elements, but `//` at the beginning of the expression would start the search from the *root of the document tree*. You need to make the search specific to every `div` in the list by prepending a dot:

```
[x.xpath(".//a/text()") for x in testing]
    # HERE^
```

Or, if applicable in your case, you can just do it in one go in a single expression:

```
x.xpath("//div/a/text()")
```